# Using the twilio api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm creating a rails app using the twilio api.

They say to get a recording you would use the url /2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Recordings/{RecordingSid}

How would you create the routes for this url?

Comment: You should be using the [`twilio-ruby`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As @sjagr rightfully points out in the comments, there is a twilio-ruby gem that can be used to make creating the URLs and making the API requests easier.

May I also suggest you take a look through this [getting started with Rails and Twilio blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html), written by my colleague Carter.

Please let me know if there's anything else I can do to help.